# Validating a checkbox in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a form with a checkbox:

```
<input id="check_agb" type="checkbox" value name="check_agb">
```

It is a needed field so I set this:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    ...
    'check_agb' => 'required',
    ...
]);
```

However it never gets validated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving the checkbox a value